# OleDbException entering decimal into decimal not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

So I'm trying to save my data set into my database

what is not working : The decimal in column 1

What I've tried :

- Put the column 1 as integer : it worked
- Set the column to any decimal precision none work
- Try to deal with the cell validating and do a try parse conclusion the cell type is double but I still get criteria mismatch
- Bang my head to the wall , not worked if you must know

```
    Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Mokmeuh.accdb")
```

`con.Open()

    Dim cmb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter)


    Try
        dAdapter.Update(dSet.Tables("Articles_table"))
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException)
    End Try
End Using`

The error itself would be :
OleDbException -2147217913 ¸
wich is a criteria mismatch but the things is I put A DAMN DECIMAL INTO THE CELLL .... i'm really piss I can't see why is not working

the column property would be 

    Field size : Decimal
    Format : Currency/General (Neither work)
    Precision : 15
    Scale : 2

I really need some help I need someone ....

Comment: so what is the physical structure of the column in ms-access...  If the column is integer based, it should ALWAYS choke trying to insert any sort of decimal/float/double based data type.

Comment: @DRapp
it's defined check the column property it's a number, decimal, formar : Currency

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'm not specifically seeing is your command builder not having a call go "GetUpdateCommand()" which generates the necessary SQL-Update command to apply any changes to the dataset